# Cannot resolve symbol view

Tags: java, android-studio

this `public void onClick (View view)` gives error

> cannot resolve symbol view

whats the issue?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view){
                //view){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Did you import view? (`import android.view.view`)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is mostly just a typo, but to point out the problem, you are passing an instance of anonymous class to the `Button#setOnClickListener` method.  The correct syntax for this is:

```
btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
});
```

Note carefully that the anonymous class is demarcated using `{ ... }` braces, in which you are overriding and providing an alternative implementation for the `onClick()` method.